# How to sanitizing phone number before searching in multi search field?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in which a user can search a MySQL database for email, phone, and username. All numbers in the database are 10 digit (1231231234) format.

IF (big if there) the user enters a phone number in the following format(s) I want it to be sanitized into just a 10 digit string as it correlates in the database:

```
(123)123-1234
123-123-1234
123.123.1234
+1(123)123-1234
11231231234
```

Usernames and emails are allowed to have . and - characters. Hence I don't know how to use PHP to determine if it is in one of these formats and then sanitize it accordingly. Ideas?

Comment: You will need to handle this in PHP, before you insert into MySQL.  A little bit of regex magic can probably handle this.

Comment: Please see ITU-T Recommendation E.164 about telephone numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164 Don't use numeric data types to store telephone "numbers".

Answer (score 0):

This will remove anything you need to remove from phone numbers or any other value. Simply update the array if you need to remove other things.

```
$string = str_replace(array('-',' ','.','(',')',',','"','+'),'',$string);
```

Comment: That breaks - and . in emails addresses. No go.

Comment: There might have to be something recognizing a 10 or 11 digit numeral string separated with certain characters and then remove them accordingly.

Comment: You asked about phone numbers @tony not email addresses. There are much easier and cleaner ways to validate  email addresses.

Comment: Reread the original post, the field accepts email addresses, phone numbers, AND user names. In the event that someone enters a phone number I would want it to sanitize

Answer (score 0):

[libphonenumber](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) can properly reformat phone numbers to a common format, adding international codes where appropriate, and then it can be stored in the database as a simple, searchable string.

Comment: That looks like it might do the job, I was looking for something a bit more lightweight though.